# Defining R package within another R package

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to define an R package within another R package and achieving functionality of only being able to access the inner R package through the outer? Say that I am building an R package that corresponds to a db layer, and that within the db layer I have a lot of sql statements, is it possible to define a package db where functions would be accessed through, db::db1::function1() where db1 is the package that is defined within db, or would the approach be to use environments to bind together the functionality as I would want to have some logical coherence between the two? So that rather I would have db::db1$ function where the db1 is an environment defined in db.

Edited example:

main folder use case:

./folder1
    ./folder1a
    ./folder1b
    ./folder1c
    ...
  ./folder2
  ./folder3
  ...

The way I envisioned was that if each folder in the hierarchy that in turns contains dussins of scripts would be a package. How would I do the mapping to packages? What would be the alternative, that each folder1 folder2 etc are the packages and the functionality in folder1a folder1b etc would be tied to an environment that lives inside the package that would correspond to folder1. Which would allow accessing some function defined in a file inside folder1a say through folder1::folder1a::function_defined_in_script_in_1a.

Comment: Can you just define functions within your package and not @export them?

Comment: Yes that would be an idea to make them non accessible from outside package. But one thing that comes to mind now is that would need add a reference back to the package db from db1 I guess as that is the way I am thinking but maybe I am confusing myself, but thank you for that idea though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making some functions "only accessible through another package", or more generally, what are you trying to achieve by attempting to "restrict access" to certain functions?

Comment: You might be looking for `requireNamespace`, which loads and registers a package, but does not attach it to the search path like `library`. So, you would prefix with the namespace for access as in your example.

Comment: I was trying to achieve a design pattern where I could use packages within packages to be able to use fully documented code, using roxygen2 for documenting and achieving encapsulation by using one package as a wrapper addiitonal layer of the inner packages. So traversing from package1->package2 and using the functions in package2 while generating the chain package1->package2 dynamically from yet another package.

Comment: I can't identify anything in your descriptions that aren't already possible using the normal tools for importing and then using functions from other packages. (Although I can only barely make sense of what you're trying to describe at all...) Perhaps if you edited your question to provide a simple concrete example of something that you want to do but can't using any standard method.

Comment: Thank you Joran for following up, have edited the question to try and clarify the structure I had in mind, i.e. mapping folders packages inside one and other.

Comment: I agree with @joran. I don't see why you can't achieve what you want through the typical packaging system.

Comment: R packages care nothing for folder hierarchy structures. And they don't deal in "scripts", they deal in functions. Tightly related functions go in the same package. Functions from other packages are accessed via importing. How you've arranged your current scripts in your file system is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping out with this I think I have confused myself a bit, and have since come up with another design that avoids these difficulties.